# extract values from a config file and pass on as arguments

Tags: python, python-2.7

Here's my config file:

```
[account1]

username = user1

password = pwd1

[account2]
username = user2

password = pwd2

[account3]
username = user3

password = pwd3
```

Here's what I need to do:

Read confile file, extract username and password and pass them on as arguments to another script.
I would like to extract the values and pass them on the fly to the second script.
**I don't want to build another dictionary in between.**

Here's my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import ConfigParser

conf = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()

conf.read('credentials.cfg')

for each_account in conf.sections():

           USER = conf.get(each_account, "username")

           PASSWORD = conf.get(each_account, "password")

process(USER, PASSWORD)
```

Output: It's calling the process only once using user3 and pwd3. Why are the other 2 credentials not being passed?

Comment: Indentation is important in Python. If your call to `process(USER, PASSWORD)` is not indented correctly, it will be called only once after your `for` loop is completed.

Comment: `process(USER, PASSWORD)` is outside the loop. maybe you should indent it?

Comment: you are overwriting your value in each iteration of the loop but call `process` after the loop ends, so it only runs once on the latest value. perhaps you should put `process` in the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't you want to process each USER and PASSWORD?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import ConfigParser

conf = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
conf.read('credentials.cfg')
for each_account in conf.sections():
           USER = conf.get(each_account, "username")
           PASSWORD = conf.get(each_account, "password")
           process(USER, PASSWORD)
```